# How to use a method as a function pointer in Rust

Tags: methods, types, rust, function-pointers, traits

I have a trait method that needs to mutate internal data of a struct and I was hoping I could pass a setter method as a parameter to the trait method. I want to do this so that I can be flexible with what gets mutated by specifying the function passed as a parameter.

This code is a simplification of what I am trying to do, it has the same compiler issue.

Thanks

**Code**

```
struct MyStruct {
    i: usize
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn set_i(mut self, i: usize) -> Self {
        self.i = i;
        self
    }
    fn new() -> Self{
        MyStruct{ i: 0 }
    }
}

trait MyTrait {
    fn do_some_setting(&mut self, setter_function: fn(&mut Self, usize) -> Self ) {
        setter_function(&mut self, 7);
    }
}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}


fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct::new()
                .set_i(3);
                
    assert_eq!(s.i, 3);
    
    s.do_some_setting(MyStruct::set_i);
    
    assert_eq!(s.i, 7);
}
```

**Problem**

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:27:23
   |
27 |     s.do_some_setting(MyStruct::set_i);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&mut MyStruct`, found struct `MyStruct`
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut MyStruct, _) -> MyStruct`
                 found fn item `fn(MyStruct, _) -> MyStruct {MyStruct::set_i}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work because `MyTrait::do_some_setting` expects a function whose first parameter is of type `&mut Self` whereas the first parameter of `MyStruct::set_i` is of type `mut self`.

You can fix this by changing the signature of `MyStruct::set_i` to `set_i(&mut self, i: usize)` but then the compiler would complain about `mismatched types` as it expects `MyStruct::set_i` to return `Self` but you'd be returning `&mut Self`. You can either derive `Clone` and return the struct after cloning it, or you can change the return type in the signature to `&mut Self`.

The compiler will once again complain about mismatched types as `setter_function` in `MyTrait::do_some_setting` is a function that returns `Self`, not `&mut Self`. You'll have to change the signature of `setter_function` to return `&mut Self`.

The compiler will now complain that `temporary value dropped while borrowed` at `let mut s = MyStruct::new().set_i(3)`. You'll have to create `MyStruct` first and then use `set_i` on it.

At last, you'll end up with code that looks as follows:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    i: usize,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn set_i(&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut Self {
        self.i = i;
        self
    }
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct { i: 0 }
    }
}

trait MyTrait {
    fn do_some_setting(&mut self, setter_function: fn(&mut Self, usize) -> &mut Self) {
        setter_function(self, 7);
    }
}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct::new();
    s.set_i(3);

    assert_eq!(s.i, 3);

    s.do_some_setting(MyStruct::set_i);

    assert_eq!(s.i, 7);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c865034e7fc71de9fcbe36171c5b3d4)